# sql constant function causes inferior query plan to be used

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I'm on SQL Server 2016 and am seeing the following:

I have a simple query similar to:

```
select distinct col1
from tbl
where
    col2 > 12345
```

If I move the constant value into a function, the query plan changes (for the worse, by A LOT):

```
select distinct col1
from tbl
where
    col2 > dbo.fn12345()
```

where the function is

```
create function dbo.fn12345() 
returns int 
as begin 
    return 12345 
end
```

here are screenshots of the plans (using my actual schema so the identifiers are different than the illustrative example.

without function:
[image: without function]

with function:
[image: with function]

With the 2nd plan my execution time goes from 22s to 96s.

Is there any way to fix this while still using functions?

Please no questions asking why I just can't inline the constant.  The same issue occurs for more complex functions that include sargable logic- inlining what is effectively a complex constant calculation changes the query plan.

I am also aware that my index is not optimal.  This is by design.  The table is very large and this particular query doesn't warrant the storage for a dedicated index.

Comment: Scalar UDFs in where clauses are famous for being problematic. Interestingly I can't repro on dbfiddle though. There it is evaluated once and used in a seek. Maybe this is an area that has been improved. What is your @@version? http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7056d010e684b76f727bd4f38c433196

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU2) (KB4013106) - 13.0.4422.0 (X64)

Comment: you may have a tough time repro'ing due to statstics and the table has i think 300MM rows.  also i'm using option (use hint ('DISABLE_OPTIMIZED_NESTED_LOOP')) as a speed up.  without the hint it does a sort and spills to tempdb.

Comment: reading this now which seems relevant http://novicksoftware.com/proposed-solution-to-the-performance-problem-with-sql-server-scalar-udfs/ and https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/273443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always going to run into problems with functions in where clauses.
even something as straightforward as ISNULL() can change the plan.
Is there any way you can persist the computed result in a table (even a temp table)? Then you can cross join to this. 
NB - Create stats on your table as this will help the optimizer.

```
    SELECT 12345 as val into #t
    select distinct col1
    from tbl
    CROSS JOIN #t
    where
    col2 > val
```

Comment: wow, are you kidding!?!?!?  the query is used as an ITVF so temp tables are out.  i'll give it a try... but wow.  are there any good blogs that discuss this issue/workaround?

Comment: omfg.  ITVF selecting a constant works.  what a bunch of crap!  for anyone following along see the following connect issue open since 2007! https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/273443

Comment: Ok. If your function doesn't take any parameters then you can write it as a view. SQL server will then "inline" the sql in the view into your main query and it will work like a constant.